# Why is :after pseudo-element rendering inside child element instead of the selected element?

Tags: css, html, sass, pseudo-element

I have the problem that my pseudo-element(:after) is rendering inside the child element instead of after the actual element! This is problematic because I am unable to position the pseudo-element the way I want to! Any ideas how to get around that?

```css
      .step__content {
            margin-top: 120px;

            div.ui-accordion-header {
                margin-left: 30px;

                :after {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    height: 20px;
                    width: 20px;
                    left: 0;
                    background-image: url('../images/i.svg');
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

As you can see on the image, its rendering inside the span for some reason! I need to render after the div!

Comment: Doesn't look like css... but maybe `&:after {` if it was `less`

Comment: Seems you are using a preprocessor, and what you have wrote is actually correct; you are targeting the `:after` pseudo-element that is a child of `.ui-accordion` which itself is a child of `.step__content`... If you want the element to be applied to `.step__content` you would have to declare it directly after it along with maybe an `&` symbol so it targets the `:after` element of `.step__content`

Comment: Is your issue persisting when doing this in vanilla CSS? If so, please share the compiled CSS, instead. If not, please clarify that this is only on Sass

Comment: @AlonEitan don't understand why, but your suggestion wroked! :)

Comment: @kontenurban It worked because it creates the following selector `.step__content div.ui-accordion-header:after` instead of ``.step__content div.ui-accordion-header :after`` (Note the space after `:after`)

Answer (score 0):

Have to set the parent to position:relative? This is where the absolutely positioned element gets its origin reference.

```
div.ui-accordion-header {
  position: relative;
  ....
}
```

Comment: I believe when he said "rendering inside", he was referring to the DOM/HTML itself, rather than visually.